# Unable to see typed data in React Text Field

Tags: react-hooks

I am Unable to see the typed data in the Input Field,But I am able see that when I console log it
What's Wrong in that Input field?? Can anyone please help me in this... Thanks in Advance...

```
const [getData, setgetData] = useState({
    name : '',
    image : '',
    price : '',
    qty : '',
    info : ''
})

 const updateData = (e) => {
    console.log({...getData,[e.target.name]:e.target.value});
 }

<input
   required
   name ="name"
   value={getData.name}
   onChange={updateData}
   type="text" 
   className="form-control"
   placeholder="Name"
/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're just doing the console.log of the data in `updateData` function.

```
const updateData =(e) =>{
   console.log({...getData,[e.target.name]:e.target.value});
}
```

You need to store it in the state.

Comment: Yes, I stored in the State and Now It is working Fine, Thank you